# wpf combo box default value

Tags: wpf, combobox, datatrigger

I'm trying to default the Combo Box selected item to index = 0 when the SelectedValue is Null. What is wrong with the data trigger ?
Error: SelectedIndex is not recognized property

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="ACombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource AList}}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="TypeName" SelectedValuePath="TypeName" 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding  AnObj.Type, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                        <ComboBox.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ComboBox.Triggers>
                    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it by creating a style trigger like below

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ACombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource AList}}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="TypeName" SelectedValuePath="TypeName" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding  AnObj.Type, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox>
```

The error says that `it does not have a qualifying type name` so by creating a style it apply to Combobox when you set the `TargetType="ComboBox"`

---

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ACombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding AList}"
            DisplayMemberPath="TypeName" SelectedValuePath="TypeName" 
            SelectedValue="{Binding  AnObj.Type, Mode=TwoWay}"   >
  <ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

This works for me.

---

Example with StaticResource

```
     <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="StringList" Type="System:String">
            <System:String>Line 1</System:String>
            <System:String>Line 2</System:String>
            <System:String>Line 3</System:String>
            <System:String>Line 4</System:String>
       </x:Array>       
    </Window.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource StringList}" >
      <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
  </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Abin: I got an exception : Items Collection must be empty before using Items Source.

Comment: Alist is a static resource defined in xaml. If I take this style out everything works fine and I get no errors.

Comment: Put your Style in `ComboBox.Resources` @AbinMathew .  Either way I still can't get SelectedIndex working except on startup

Comment: Anyone knows how to make it work with a static resource ?

Comment: @AbinMathew this does not work: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/df5a2b9f3f393543367ddf5c02d2f6ff

Comment: This doesn't either: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/52fc9a3ddd04ed4bb8e654f1ad569650

Comment: @NewUser Try changing `ACombob.SelectedValue = null;` to `ACombob.SelectedItem = null;` as the Trigger.

Comment: @Kevin This is working for me.   https://gist.github.com/abinmatthew/87ff68def26fc5ebf50676667d956f40

Comment: @AbinMathew You forgot to bind the SelectedItem. That would change the behavior and it would not work anymore.

Comment: I have changed <Trigger Property="SelectedItem" Value="{x:Null}"> To <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}"> and it worked fine. What is the Difference between Trigger and DataTrigger ?

Comment: @NewUser Its your decision to bind with SelectedItem or SelectedValue as i dont know what are you binding with. you mentioned its a static resource thats all. we are here to help you not to code for you. i have already answered the question which is asked for and willing to help again. dont think that we code for you. about Triggers there are three kinds of triggers as i know, Property trigger, Data Trigger and Event Trigger. google is your best friend to find out what is the difference between these there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you All for your help.